# Elastic potential energy formula

Tags: energy, potential-energy, elasticity, deformation-quantization

From the [Wikipedia page on elastic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_energy), we can find a bunch of formulas to describe it. For example, in the continuum section it talks about energy per unit of volume (density?):

$U=\dfrac{1}{2}C_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}$

Where $C_{ijkl}$ is the elastic tensor and $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ is the strain tensor.

Why doesn't it talk about energy itself? To obtain it, would it be as easy as multiplying $U$ by the volume $V$?

And does this equation hold true for non-linear cases or big deformations? Shouldn't we integrate over all components of the product? According to that, the total energy $E$ in a region $D$ with volume $V$ would be:

$E=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_DC_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}dV$

Is this equation correct to designate the total elastic energy contained in the specified rigion? In which cases this is the proper equation and in which cases is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it talk about energy itself? To obtain it, would it be as
> easy as multiplying U by the volume V?

Normally (a table over the floor for example) the strain is not constant, so the elastic energy is a function of the point. By multiplying the energy density by the volume of a small neighbourhood around a point, we can approximate the energy of that small volume.

> And does this equation hold true for non-linear cases or big
> deformations?

If $C's$ are constants, it is restricted to linear cases. For linear cases with large deformations (as a fishing rod), we can use the formula by rotating the system of coordinates so that if $z$ is the longitudinal direction for a point of the rod, it is also longitudinal for other points.

> Is this equation correct to designate the total elastic energy
> contained on the specified region?

Yes, for linear and small deformation cases.

Comment: Regarding the last, proposed formula, wouldn't it apply to large deformations as well? You would be summing up for every infinitesimal strain caused in the volume. And why would it only work for a linear case?

Comment: The problem with large deformation is that the integral supposes a fixed system of coordinates. It doesn't rotate along the body. Linear case because multiplying the elasticity tensor by the strain tensor is a linear operation.